# How to fetch the latest 25 entries from an App-Engine datastore entity kind

Tags: java, sorting, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have an entity kind (i.e. ~table) with thousands of entries. I want to fetch the latest 25 entries. How do I do that? The following logic is not working: it returns the oldest 25.

```
Filter timestampFilter = new FilterPredicate("lastestEditDate", FilterOperator.GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL, 0);
Query query = new Query(CatMeow.class.getSimpleName()).setFilter(timestampFilter);

FetchOptions options = FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(25);
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
QueryResultList<Entity> entities = datastore.prepare(query).asQueryResultList(options);
```

I believed I needed to change my logic entirely. Having thought about it, I didn’t think a timestamp filter was relevant. So I changed to the following logic, which also is not working: it’s not returning the latest entities.

```
Query query = new Query(CatMeow.class.getSimpleName()).
            addSort("lastestEditDate", SortDirection.ASCENDING);
FetchOptions options = FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(25);
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
QueryResultList<Entity> entities = datastore.prepare(query).asQueryResultList(options);
```

So again, of thousands of entities, I need to grab the latest 25 that were added. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SortDirection.ASCENDING` means to get the oldest entities (i.e the ones with the smallest values of `lastestEditDate`) first.

What you want is exactly the opposite -- **newest** entities (i.e the ones with the **largest** values of `lastestEditDate`) first.

Therefore, use, instead, `SortDirection.DESCENDING`.

Comment: I already tried that. It made no difference. It still does not get me the latest 25. Instead, it gets me some earlier set arrange in different order. So it seems the ordering is done after the wrong set is fetched. I need to fetch the correct set.

Comment: If the `lastestEditDate` was set correctly (although spelled wrong:-) the code should work -- fetching does depend on order.  Can you edit the Q to show (A) how `CatMeow` entities are built, and (B) a small sample of what you're getting (just a bunch of 5 should be fine, no need to show 25, nor any need to show all properties beyond `lastestEditDate` and, say, a distinguishing name property of some sort) and other entities which you think you should get instead.  I think the problem is somewhere in the un-shown parts of the code, not in the part you show.

Comment: @KatedralPillon, thanks for the accept!, but can you please explain (editing your Q, or in a comment) how you solved the problem, so future readers with a similar problem can benefit from your experience?  Thanks!

Comment: I didn't have the index set, so the query was returning 500. I didn't notice it. So your answer is actually correct. I just forgot to set it as an index.